# Iterate through a foreach loop backwards in PHP

Tags: php

I have here a foreach loop that displays images from a database onto a webpage. What I would like to do is iterate through the foreach loop backwards, so the latest content is shown first on the webpage. Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'UPLOADPICS'";

    if ($sth = $dbhandle->query($sql)){
        if ($sth->fetchColumn() > 0){
            $sql = "SELECT link FROM 'UPLOADPICS'";
            foreach ($dbhandle->query($sql) as $row){
                $content = $row['link'];
                ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $content ?>" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <?php
            }
        }

        else {
            print "No rows matched the query";
        }
```

Is this possible? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Add a `ORDER BY` to loop in the order wanted. And you don't need to count before querying...

Comment: why don't you sort the result in the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't have a date field in your table .. you can order by id in a Descending order

```
    $sql = "SELECT link FROM `UPLOADPICS` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
```

if you don't like that you can use array_reverse() function

Comment: This worked great! I'm using SQLite so the 'rowid' is already there.
For those wondering, here is my syntax for displaying the reverse order:

`$sql = "SELECT link FROM 'UPLOADPICS' ORDER BY rowid DESC";`

Answer (score 6):

Rather than looping backwards, you could order your results with [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) to show the most recent items first. This is typically the most common method used.

```
SELECT foo, bar 
FROM uploadpics 
ORDER BY 
  date DESC
```

Of course this is more than a mere suggestion; you won't be able to run through the values in reverse anyway without first loading them into a new array collection, and then iterating over that backwards - so you'd be wasting some precious time and resources.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    for ($i = count($a) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        echo $a[$i];
    }
    echo "\n";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a count of the array and iterate through it backwards using a simple index variable that decreases by 1 through each iteration.

```
$arr = $dbhandle->query($sql);
$i = count($arr) - 1;

while ($i >= 0)
{
    $content = $arr[$i]['link'];
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $content ?>" />
    <?php
    $i--;
}
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go!
One question, in //do $arr[$i];, is this where i display the images?

Answer (score 0):

well including `Order By` would be more appropriate but you may not have date field!

using php's [array_reverse() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) would reverse the array; in your case first reverse the array and then apply foreach.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array("uno"=>array(1),"pepito"=>array(1),"clase"=>array(1),"a123"=>array(1));
echo 'normal<br>';
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    echo $k." = ".$v."<br>";
}
echo 'back<br>';
foreach(array_reverse($array) as $k=>$v){
    echo $k." = ".$v."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Some explanation to go with the code would not go amiss, I think.